# Azure Pipelines - Insert a variable value into a JSON with PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm working in an Azure Pipelines (not inline) where I'm trying to insert a variable's value into a JSON file, the mentioned file is download from a storage account and read during the process, so far so good. The files contains something as below

```json
{"MedUnits":[
    {
        "System":"Med",
        "UnitName":"MedicalUnitEast",
        "MedID":"",
        "Assigments":[
        {
            "Measur":"Density",
            "Unit":"m3"
        },
        {
            "Measur":"Weight",
            "Unit":"kg"
        }
    ]}
]}
```

I need to insert the variable value for the MedID key that is always empty, I've been trying different ways (math/replace, if) but I'm getting errors for some cmdlet. This is an example of what I've tried:

```
#Downloading file from storageaccount
$unitsFile = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/folder/${json}?sv=TOKEN"
```

```
$JsonData = Get-Content -Path .\$unitsFile | ConvertFrom-Json
$JsonData.update | % { if($JsonData.MedUnits.MedID){
                                    $JsonData.MedUnits.MedID= "$ID"
                            }
                        }
$JsonData | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4  | set-content $unitsFile
```

It seems I'm doing something wrong as I'm getting the error "**##[error]Get-Content : Illegal characters in path.**" during pipeline execution, and if I remove the **-Path .(backslash)** after the Get-Content, I get another error stating **##[error]Get-Content : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '{"MedUnits"' does not exist.**

Comment: The implication is that `$unitsFile` isn't a _file path_, as you expect,  but the file's _content_ (JSON). If so, simply use `$JsonData = $unitsFile | ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: Is `MedId` always a direct child of `MedUnits` ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon yes, it always is.

Comment: @mklement0 I tried as you suggested but I'm getting the same error message but now for the Set-Content and if I remove it I get another error stating "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline"

Comment: @GTGabaaron, well if `$unitsFile` isn't a file path, you also cannot use it with `Set-Content`; you'll have to specify a file path differently.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried below code in my Local and Azure Pipelines Powershell task and the MedID was updated successfully. Make sure the path to your Json file is correct while running your script.

***Local:-***

**Script:-**

```
$unitsFile="C:\Logic-app\Medunits.json"
$ID="1233"

$JsonData = Get-Content -Path $unitsFile -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$JsonData.MedUnits[0].MedID = $ID
$JsonData | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4 | Set-Content $unitsFile
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

***Azure DevOps Powershell Task:-***

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $unitsFile="$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Medunits.json"
      $unitsFile
      $ID="1244"
      
      $JsonData = Get-Content -Path $unitsFile -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
      $JsonData.MedUnits[0].MedID = $ID
      $JsonData | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4 | Set-Content $unitsFile
      $JsonData
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm not using the inline script method, I'm calling a script file (File Path method) from the Azure Repo, therefore using "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Medunits.json" is not working. ---> The term 'System.DefaultWorkingDirectory' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. If there another way to call if from inside the file ?

Comment: Make sure the script path is correct, Can you run the pipeline by Enabling Diagnostics Logging and check the path?